# Azure Pipelines - Clone or Copy Hosted Agent

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-hosted-agent

Is it possible to clone or copy an Azure Pipeline Hosted Agent for use as a Self-Hosted Agent?
I'd like to reuse one of the Hosted Agents simply to enable me recreate and reuse all of its
capabilities, saving me the headache. Is this possible and if so I'd really appreciate some help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible, but you can try to reuse what is already available here https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments

> This repository contains the source used to create the virtual environments for GitHub Actions hosted runners, as well as the VM images of Microsoft-hosted agents used for Azure Pipelines. To file bug reports, or request that tools be added/updated, please open an issue using the appropriate template. To build a VM machine from this repo's source, see the instructions.

So you can use the same scripts which are used to create Microsoft Hosted agents.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such build-in feature.

- Azure DevOps provides free hosted agents that have a predefined set
  of tools installed and configured for building and releasing your
  apps.
- There is another option where you set up and manage your own agents.
  This can be done by simply downloading the agent package, and run it
  either on your local machine or any other computing platform even on
  Docker container. It also gives you more freedom to install specific
  dependencies for your build and release.

If you want to build your own agent during the pipeline. I would suggest you use **Docker** container to handle the process.

Microsoft has already created pre-configured [container images on Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-azure-pipelines-vsts-agent?tab=description) for everybody to use. But they’re Linux based and don’t contain any additional applications and/or packages so you’d probably still need to add those every time you run your build.

> This repository contains images for the Visual Studio Team Services
> (VSTS) agent that runs tasks as part of a build or release.
>
> VSTS agent images are tagged according to the base OS, an optional
> Team Foundation Server (TFS) version, and tools that are installed.
>
> When used with VSTS, the agent version is automatically determined and
> downloaded at container startup based on the account to which the
> agent is connecting.

More detail step, you could refer this article: **[Build your own Azure DevOps agents with pipelines](https://medium.com/wortell/build-your-own-azure-devops-agents-with-pipelines-95104be095d5)**